# CSS superscript registration trademark

Tags: css

I would like all "®" on a site to be in superscript.  Can I do that with CSS?

Comment: superscripting is semantic information, not just presentational.  So it is far more appropriate to use <sup> tags than CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding <sup> tags around all trademark and registered trademark symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364581/adding-sup-tags-around-all-trademark-and-registered-trademark-symbols)

Comment: Please note that ® rendering superscript or not is a font issue. Some fonts render the symbol as superscript, some don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you asked CSS but this jQuery code worked for me, hope it helps you

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("body").html(
                    $("body").html().replace("®", "<sup>&reg;</sup>")
                ); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some text here &reg;
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work until I used the unicode value for the symbol: .replace("\u00AE", ....

Comment: my browser's not responding after using your snippet ;)

Comment: If there are any reg marks rendered out inside attributes of HTML elements, you may end up with broken markup.  I wouldn't recommend this approach.  No alternative than altering the output on the server before rending in my opinion.

Comment: In addition, if any elements in the DOMhave already been bound in javascript they are stale. Using this method you're detaching the existing DOM and forcing the browser to reparse the entire body.

Answer (score 30):

AverageAdam's answer will work fine, but if you for some reason wanted a CSS version, you could do this:

```
.sup { vertical-align: super; }
```

and

```
<span class="sup">&reg;</span>
```

From [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-text-properties/).

Comment: caution: this can screw up your leading (line spacing) as shown here : `http://new.moorecreative.com/Articles/Detail/tabid/522/ArticleId/10/Why-cant-you-superscript-a-registered-mark-%C2%AE-Email-superscript-issues-explained.aspx`. the solution by @zematdev can help fix this

Answer (score 13):

add this to your html file `<sup>your mark here</sup>`

then add this to your css

```
sup {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40%;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    top: -1.2em;
}
```

You can adjust the height of the mark using "top" in the css and the size with "font-size". This will also work for any TM, SM, or symbol you want. It will not effect any of your spacing or typography.

Answer (score 10):

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Unfortunately CSS doesn't have a way to specify superscript's. You can however simulated it using a span and some tags.

**Correction 2021:** As others have mentioned there are many ways including using CSS. Based on the various options and issues presented in this question I've created a pen to demonstrate options for [superscript styling and line-height fixes](https://codepen.io/ahewgill/pen/zYZBjww).

My personal favorite is `position:relative` since it doesn't require the `line-height:0` fix. Thanks @osuthorpe

Comment: Note: I was wrong about CSS not having a super property. Thanks JasonWyatt.

Comment: link now broken

Comment: I've corrected the response and changed the link to an example pen. Thanks @foson

Answer (score 6):

use the CSS below to create a  tag that doesn't mess with your leading. Adjust values as needed. Font-size is optional, I used it to make my r-balls a little smaller than the registered trademarked text.

```
sup{
 vertical-align: 75%;
 line-height: 5px;
 font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: very important point here - the line spacing (leading) is screwed up even when you use `vertical-align: super` which is kind of rediculous. a block of text with a &reg; in the middle line will appear taller than the others

Answer (score 2):

Victor's answer only worked for the first Reg mark on my page. I found this code to work on the entire page. Hope it helps someone:

```
$("body").html(
   $("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
);
```

found it here: http://www.cmexsolutions.com/blog/use-jquery-to-superscript-all-register-marks-reg-or-%C2%AE

Answer (score 2):

I've used the CSS below for positioning the trademark registration symbol ® in HTML whereby the result is the ® symbol with a link, smaller and above the normal text.  Note there are two links in the example.  The reason for this is because I wanted the main anchor link to be underlined and the ® symbol to be not underlined.

```
.trademark {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40%;
  top: -1.2em;
}

.no-style {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Example with CSS using JSX in React:

```
 <a href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com">Photo Prints Now</a><a 
 href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com" className="no-style"><span 
 className="trademark">®</span></a>
```

Example in HTML with CSS where the syntax is class instead of className:

```
 <a href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com">Photo Prints Now</a><a 
 href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com" class="no-style"><span class="trademark">®</span> 
 </a>
```

Example in HTML with STYLE:

```
 <a href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com">Photo Prints Now</a>
 <a href="https://www.photoprintsnow.com" style="text-decoration: none; "> 
 <span style="position: relative;font-size: 40% ;top: -1.2em;">®</span>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the previous answers, I'd suggest that superscript is presentational rather than semantic, and therefore styling the registration mark should be done using CSS. Whether superscripted or not, a registration mark is still a registration mark, and would be recognised as a registration mark by humans/computers. The symbol itself may be considered semantic, in that it gives a 'special' meaning to the object to which it relates, but the styling of it is entirely presentational. By convention the registration mark is often (but not always) superscripted, as is the trademark symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with some of the scripts above is that they don't deal with the fact that there might already exist some <sup>®</sup> elements on the page. In this case, they will be replaced with: <sup><sup>®</sup></sup>.

I think a solution like this might make more sense.

```
$("body").html(
   $("body").html().replace(/<sup>&reg;<\/sup>/gi, '&reg;').
        replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').
        replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind using jQuery:

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>'));
});
```

it works much faster than modyfying whole `body` tag (as in [Robert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093237/1145274) and [Victor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704170/1145274) answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use regex, why not clean it up with one call

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,dd,dt,a").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/(<sup>)?(&reg;|®)(<\/sup>)?/gi, '<sup>®</sup>'));
});
```

I don't recommend doing this on the body like the OP ended up doing. It could interfere with inline javascript that might have the symbol in it.

Comment: and generally i'd call this a bad idea anyway.  better to just have your HTML set right.  when you must use this, be aware that it could break other javascripts like events attached to content inside a p tag.  You are essentially replacing the DOM inside these tags with new html, so any javascript parsing and adding of events and such that happened before you did this would be lost.

Comment: to minimize unwanted impact, you could improve it by DETECTING the symbols before just doing a blind html replace on everything.