# Adding superscript <sup> tags around all trademark and registered trademark symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, symbols, superscript

I am trying to add `<sup></sup>` tags around every ™, ®, © in my page.

I found this question: [CSS superscript registration trademark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703961/css-superscript-registration-trademark/1704170#1704170) which helped get me started.

The script works in the sense that the tags are being placed in the proper locations, but it is adding two `<sup></sup>` tags around each instead of just one.

Here is my JS adding the tags:

```
jQuery("body").html(
    jQuery("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').
        replace(/&trade;/gi, '<sup>&trade;</sup>').
        replace(/™/gi, '<sup>&trade;</sup>').
        replace(/&copy;/gi, '<sup>&copy;</sup>').
        replace(/©/gi, '<sup>&copy;</sup>')
);
```

How can I make sure the tags are only added once per symbol? A conditional of some sort maybe?

Comment: What happens if you only replace `™` (not `&trade;`). And the other way around? I suspect `jQuery("body").html()` is doing some implicit conversion.

Comment: Thats what I initially thought was the issue, but removing them doesn't change anything.

Comment: Why not changing the source manually? Replacing html of the body element is so hacky and error-prone.

Comment: @TyBailey OK, so what happens if you only call `replace` once, rather than chaining several together? Does that work as expected?

Comment: As an aside, doing this on a page with a lot of content is going to be very slow. @undefined is right - change it at source!

Comment: Changing it at the source is not an option. There are FAR too many of these throughout this site. It was fine until we change the font family, then they all blew up. VisioN's answer below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of rewriting the entire markup (and removing all bound events), I'd go for something like that:

```
$('body :not(script)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/[™®©]/g, '<sup>$&</sup>');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QTfxC/

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as I am able.

Comment: Hey Vision, can you help me modify this to check if there is already a `<sup>` tag around the symbol? If it's there then don't add it via the script, if it's not then add it?

Comment: @TyBailey Sure. Just add `<sup>` tag to filter, i.e. `:not(script,sup)`. **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QTfxC/1/.

Comment: Wrapping ™ in <sup></sup> is actually not needed since it will always have upper position.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,li,a").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;   </sup>'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

@VisioN's answer didn't work that well for me, although it was facing the right direction. I tweaked it a little bit:

```
var regexp = /[\xAE]/;
$('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && (regexp.test(this.nodeValue));
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(regexp, '<sup>$&</sup>');
});
```

This method makes use of the [character hex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-hex-escape), instead of using the character code. I looked up the hex on [character-codes.com](http://character-code.com/) and picked the character hex of the ® character. The value is `AE` so that's how I got to my solution. Let me know if this one worked for you!

Comment: including `sup` in the `:not` exclusion is important if your content is coming from mixed sources or being input by multiple people, good call on that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my Drupal 8 website:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
var regexp = /[\u2122]/;
$('body :not(script,sup)').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && (regexp.test(this.nodeValue));
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace("\u2122", "<sup>&trade;</sup>");
});
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```